# datagridcomboboxcolumn binding in code

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn, programmatically-created

I'd like to do this entirely in code, no XAML:
Given are

```
DataGridComboBoxColumn myDGCBC = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
ObservableCollection<string> DataSource = new ObservableCollection<string>{"Option1", "Option2"};
myDGCBC.ItemsSource = DataSource;

ObservableCollection<MyStructure> MyObject = new ObservableCollection<MyStructure>;
```

and

```
public class MyStructure
{
   ... several properties ... // pseudocode, obviously
   public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
}
```

I am interested in (binding) receiving the selected values from all the comboxboxes in the column into the `SelectedValue` property.

I tried several ideas from SO, but to no avail.

Help!
Thanks.

Comment: @Bahman_Aries, thanks for the edit. Typo in copying from another computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a `DataGird` is already defined in xaml, you should set proper bindings for both `DataGrid` and `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

Here is an example to give you an idea:

**Xaml:**

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1"  Content="test" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.cs:**

```
    //DataGrid ItemsSource
    public ObservableCollection<MyStructure> DataSource { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        // Initializing DataGrid.ItemsSource
        DataSource = new ObservableCollection<MyStructure>();
        DataSource.Add(new MyStructure());

        // Creating new DataGridComboBoxColumn 
        DataGridComboBoxColumn myDGCBC = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
        myDGCBC.Header = "cmbColumn";

        // Binding DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource and DataGridComboBoxColumn.SelectedItem
        var cmbItems = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Option1", "Option2" };
        myDGCBC.ItemsSource = cmbItems;
        myDGCBC.SelectedItemBinding = new Binding("SelectedValue");
        // Adding DataGridComboBoxColumn to the DataGrid
        myGrid.Columns.Add(myDGCBC);

        // Binding DataGrid.ItemsSource 
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = DataSource;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(myGrid, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //This is just to check whether SelectedValue is set properly:
        string selectedValue = DataSource[0].SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: First, thanks. Would you be so kind as to do this without MVVM?

Comment: Actually It's not Mvvm at all! : ) however I modified my answer and removed some unnecessary parts. Please take a look and tell me whether it's helpful.

Comment: `myDGCBC.SelectedItemBinding = new Binding("SelectedValue");` or `myDGCBC.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("SelectedValue");`?

Comment: You are welcome, btw, both `SelectedItemBinding` and `SelectedValueBinding` works, depending on the need.